# Layout not showed with good dimension when user click on overlay button

Tags: android

I have an Android app with a Service to Overlay a button on Android (like Facebook chat bubble).
I want to show a layout (overlay.xml) when the user click on the icon but I can't show the layout with the good dimension.

This is my result :
[image]

This is my **OverlayShowingService.class** :

```
public class OverlayShowingService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;
    private Boolean _enable = true;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        _enable=false;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new ImageView(this);

        chatHead.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

        chatHead.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater   = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                popupWindow.update();

                Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                Button endService= (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.endService);
                endService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        stopSelf();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Terminated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Popup Terminated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        _enable=true;
                    }
                });

                if(_enable){
                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(chatHead, 50, -30);
                    _enable=false;
                }
                else if(!_enable) {
                    Log.d("FALSE", "FALSE");
                }
            }
        });
        try {

            chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;

                @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            initialX = paramsF.x;
                            initialY = paramsF.y;
                            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                            paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                            windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, paramsF);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }

}
```

This is the layout **overlay.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#545454">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="It's a PopupWindow"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dismiss"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dismiss Popup"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/endService"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Finish Service"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is that icon your overlay button or the result of tapping that button?

Comment: It's the overlay button and the grey part (in the bottom of the button) is the result of tapping that button.

Comment: Instead of performing `wrap_content`, why don't you specify the dimensions?

Comment: it do the same using specify dimensions instead of `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This is an alternate approach that mimics a popup window. I have kept the first answer with a altert dialog approach after the following explanation and code. Either way will work, but this new way may be preferable since it looks more like a popup window.

This approach simply adds the `overlay.xml` layout into a view that is place on the screen just like the `chatHead` view is.

**OverlayShowingService.java**

```
public class OverlayShowingService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;
    private Boolean _enable = true;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        _enable = false;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new ImageView(this);

        chatHead.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;

        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
        chatHead.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                params.x = (int) chatHead.getBottom() + 50;
                params.y = (int) chatHead.getRight() - 30;
            }
        });

        chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                popupWindow.update();

                Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                Button endService = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.endService);
                endService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        windowManager.removeViewImmediate(popupView);
                        stopSelf();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Terminated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Popup Terminated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        windowManager.removeViewImmediate(popupView);
                        _enable = true;
                    }
                });

                if (_enable) {
                    windowManager.addView(popupView, params);
//                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(chatHead, 50, -30);
                    _enable = false;
                } else if (!_enable) {
                    Log.d("FALSE", "FALSE");
                }
            }
        });
        try {

            chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
                private int initialX;
                private int initialY;
                private float initialTouchX;
                private float initialTouchY;

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            initialX = paramsF.x;
                            initialY = paramsF.y;
                            initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                            initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                            paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                            windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, paramsF);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }
}
```

---

**The first approach using an alert dialog.**

Your code works as-is for API 21 and below. Something changed with API 22 that is prohibiting what you want to do.

I think the primary issue is with the popup and the service environment. I have modified your code to use an `AlertDialog` with the type `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`. Although the styling is not what you want, it does work otherwise. You may be able to get it to style differently if you play with it a little.

Another alternative would be to start an activity from your service. An activity-based approach will present you with a more pliable (and forgiving) environment to do what you want with the UI. (This is not as straight-forward as one may think.)

Below is the code that works as a system-level alert. Here is a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf0ey.png).

**OverlayShowingService**

```
chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(arg0.getContext(),
                R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert).create();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        alertDialog.setView(popupView);
        Button btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
        Button endService = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.endService);
        endService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                stopSelf();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Terminated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Popup Terminated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my first answer, you are having this issue with API 22 and later. Your code works OK for API  21 and earlier.

You are running afoul of changes made to `PopupWindow` in API level 22. See [this documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/393b1c1).

> Fix issue #17789629: PopupWindow overlaps with navigation bar.
>
> The Lollipop release introduced a feature that allowed
>   apps to extend under the navigation bar. This also means
>   any popup window that is anchored to the bottom of its
>   parent window will overlap with the navigation bar if the
>   parent window is extending underneath the navigation bar.
>
> This change introduces a new window flag
>   (FLAG_LAYOUT_ATTACHED_IN_DECOR) that allows the app to
>   specify if the popup window should be attached to the decor
>   frame of the parent window thereby avoiding an overlap
>   with the screen decorations.
>
> By default the flag is set on SDK version LOLLIPOP_MR1 or
>   greater and cleared on lesser SDK versions.

You can turn off this flag with the [setAttachedInDecor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setAttachedInDecor(boolean)) method of `PopupWindow`.

Add the following code to `OverlayShowingService.java` after `popupWindow.update()` in the `OnClickListener` and you should be good to go.

```
// Turn off this functionality introduced in API 22.
// See documentation for FLAG_LAYOUT_ATTACHED_IN_DECOR in
// WindowManager.LayoutParams
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    popupWindow.setAttachedInDecor(false);
}
```